# Left nav pane drops content pane beneath it when resized from small to large

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navbar

I have a collapsible left nav pane, which when closed correctly displays the Content pane next to (right) it, but when I re-open by clicking the hamburger,  the nav pane resizes correctly, but the content gets moved beneath the Nav pane.
How to ensure it always displays to the right, irrespective of screen size (within reasonable limits).?

Thanks

My _Layout page:

```
<Html>
<body style="vertical-align:top; padding:0px">
<style>
    .btnLC {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 0px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        opacity: 1.0;
        background-color: transparent;
        display: none;
    }

   .lcContent {
        transition: margin-left .5s;
        height: 1000px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 85%;
    }
    .lcSideBar {
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #2f2c2d;
        padding-top: 20px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        float: left;
        height: 1050px;
        max-height: 1250px;
    }
    li {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .hamburger {
        background-color: black !important;
        color: darkgray !important;
        padding-left: 10px;
        border: solid 0px black;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="row" style="height: 40px; width: 100%; background-color: black; ">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align:left; ">
        <button class="btn btn-default hamburger" type="button" style="display:block; padding-left:10px; width:20%; background-color:transparent">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10" style="text-align:center; ">
        <label style="color: aqua; width: 200px; height: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; padding-top: 10px; font-size:16px">
            <span style="color:blue; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <b>My App</b>
            </span> 2
        </label>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Left Sidebar -->
<div id="lcSideBar" class="lcSideBar">
    <ul id="UL_Parent">
        <li>
            <span class="btnLCTop">
                <strong>
                    YadaYada
                </strong>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li class='btnLC'>
                    <span>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" style="background-color:#222222 !important; color:gainsboro;" level="1">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-none"></span>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class='btnLC'>AAAA</li>
                <li class='btnLC'>BBBB</li>
               
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Content Body -->
<div id="lcContent" class="container-fluid lcContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

</body>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnLC").click(function () {

        // Reduce the width of the sidebar
        document.getElementById("lcSideBar").style.width = "40px";
        document.getElementById("lcContent").style.marginLeft = "40px";

        $(this).siblings().each(function () {
            $(this).css({"display": "block"})
        });

        var url = '@Url.Action("List", "Home")';
        $("#lcContent").load(url);

        $(this).addClass("liSelected");
     });


    // Redisplays the LeftSide Nav bar at full width with transition effect, also hides the hamburger
    $(".glyphicon-menu-hamburger").on("click", function () {

        var ele = document.getElementById("lcSideBar"),
            eleStyle = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
        var eleWidth = eleStyle.width;

        var clientWidth = document.getElementById('lcSideBar').clientWidth;  // initial width = 200

        if (clientWidth == 200) {
            document.getElementById("lcSideBar").style.width = "40px";
            document.getElementById("lcContent").style.marginLeft = "40px";
            document.getElementById("lcContent").style.width = "95%";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("lcSideBar").style.width = "200px";
            document.getElementById("lcContent").style.marginLeft = "200px";
            document.getElementById("lcContent").style.width = "90%";
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: This has a lot of server-side code in your example.  This makes it harder to debug what appears to be a purely css error. Can you setup a fiddle or a public page we can view with the error?